# Using timeit on a cython function

Tags: python, cython, timeit

I am trying to time a cython compiled function with  timeit using the following syntax:

```
from offset_back import offset_back

print timeit.timeit(stmt='offset_back(10000,1000,1000)',setup='from main import offset_back',number=1000)
```

but I keep getting "cannot import name offset_back".

When I  `print(offset_back(10000,1000,1000))`
 the function gets called fine, is it possible to use timeit on cython code or do I have to use cProfile?``

Comment: Do you mean `from __main__ import offset_back` or do you actually have a module called `main`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you using different syntax in your setup than you used in your example? Why not

```
print timeit.timeit(stmt='offset_back(10000,1000,1000)',setup='from offset_back import offset_back',number=1000)
```

Comment: I thought the from main was required when calling any function, your syntax worked thanks.

Comment: 'main' is used to reference methods & objects defined within the calling module.